# Evaluate log(1 - normal_cdf(x)) in a numerically stable way

Tags: python, scipy, numerical, softmax, underflow

How to evaluate `log(1 - normal_cdf(x))` in a numerically stable way? Here, `normal_cdf` is the cumulative distribution function of the standard Normal distribution.

For example, in Python:

```
import scipy 
from scipy.stats import norm

np.log(1 - norm.cdf(10))
```

gives `-inf` with `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` since `norm.cdf(10)` is almost equal to `1`. Is there a function like `logsumexp` that can avoid numerical under-flow?

Comment: Since it is not a logarithm of a product, you can't exploit properties of the logarithm function. Check this answer for some interesting facts https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75074/an-alternative-way-to-calculate-logx

Comment: perhaps `norm.cdf(10)=1-norm.cdf(-10)` so `np.log(1 - norm.cdf(10))=np.log(norm.cdf(-10))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the normal distribution is symmetric about 0, we have

```
1 - F(x) = P(X > x)
         = P(X < -x)
         = F(-x)
```

Hence

```
np.log(1 - norm.cdf(10)) = np.log(norm.cdf(-10))
                         = norm.logcdf(-10)
```

Answer (score 2):

@HongOoi's suggestion to take advantage of the symmetry is great.  But for an arbitrary distribution in `scipy.stats` (including `norm`), you can use the method `logsf` for exactly this computation. `sf` stands for [*survival function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function), which is the name of the function `1 - cdf(x)`.

For example,

```
In [25]: import numpy as np

In [26]: from scipy.stats import norm, gamma
```

Here's an example of `norm.logsf`:

```
In [27]: norm.logsf(3, loc=1, scale=1.5)
Out[27]: -2.3945773661586434

In [28]: np.log(1 - norm.cdf(3, loc=1, scale=1.5))
Out[28]: -2.3945773661586434
```

And here's an example of `gamma.logsf`:

```
In [29]: gamma.logsf(1.2345, a=2, scale=1.8)
Out[29]: -0.16357333194167956

In [30]: np.log(1 - gamma.cdf(1.2345, a=2, scale=1.8))
Out[30]: -0.16357333194167956
```

This shows why one would want to use `logsf(x)` instead of `log(1 - cdf(x))`:

```
In [35]: norm.logsf(50, loc=1, scale=1.5)
Out[35]: -537.96178420294677

In [36]: np.log(1 - norm.cdf(50, loc=1, scale=1.5))
/Users/warren/miniconda3scipy/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/Users/warren/miniconda3scipy/bin/python
Out[36]: -inf
```